# $|G|=p^km$ ($p$ prime and $k,m\in\mathbb{N}$) , gcd($p,m)=1$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I can't solve this question, I tried proving it using the center of the group but failed to.. anyways the question :
$|G|=p^km$ ($p$ prime and $k,m\in\mathbb{N}$) , gcd($p,m)=1$.
Let $N \triangleleft G$ such that $|N|=p^k$, let $q$ be a prime such that $q|m$.
Prove $G$ has subgroup of order $p^kq$.
**My try :**
Using the gcd I found that gcd($p,q)=1$ and gcd($p^k,q)=1$.
since $N$ is a $p$-group $Z(N)\ne \{e\}\rightarrow Z(G)\ne \{e\}$
using Cauchy theorem -
I found that $\exists a\in Z(G) : o(a)=p$ and $\exists b\in Z(G) : o(b)=q$
so $|Z(G)|\in \{pq,p^2q,...,p^kq\}$ but I couldn't somehow force that $|Z(G)|=p^kq$ which will complete my proof.

I'm aware of Sylow's theorem but I would like to use only the statement - "if $|G|=p^km$ such that gcd($p,m)=1$ then exist subgroup of order $p^k$"

Any help or clue would be helpful , Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer - by Sylwo's theorem we get that for every prime that divides the order of a group exist a subgroup of that prime.
So we have a prime $q|m \rightarrow q|p^km$ so we have a subgroup of order $|H|=q$
Since $H,N<G \rightarrow HN<G$
$H\cap N < H \rightarrow |H\cap N| | q$
$H\cap N < N \rightarrow |H\cap N| | p^k$
we have found that gcd($p^k,q)=1 \rightarrow |H \cap N| =1$
$|HN|=\frac {|H|*|N|}{|H\cap N|}=\frac {p^kq}{|H\cap N|}=p^kq$
So we have found a subgroup of order $p^kq$.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your proof attempt, it is not true that we have $Z(G)\neq 1=\{e\}$. In fact, let $G=S_3$. Then $|G|=6=p^km$ with
$p=2,m=3$ or $p=3,m=2$ and $k=1$. However, we have $Z(G)=1$.

For the question, $G$ is a semidirect product of $N$ and $Q\cong G/N$, because $p^k$ and $m$ are coprime. Apply Cauchy for a subgroup of $Q$ of order $q$.

Comment: oh right , I see my bad